# How can I remove the timestamp from a date/time field in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I am joining two different tables in SQL (I am still relatively new to SQL). The first one has timestamps like `12/11/2013 23:50:12 PM` and the second like `12/11/2013 0:00` (notice the difference in time formatting). They are not joining properly because of this, so I want to remove the time portion of the timestamp, and I am unsure how to do this.

I want `12/11/2013 23:50:12 PM` and `12/11/2013 0:00` to be recognized as equivalent.

Note: I am using AWS Redshift.

Comment: Fix your data!  You should be storing date/time values using native times like `date` and `timestamp`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff ...the data was given to me. That is beyond my control

Comment: Have you tried just casting both as dates? CAST(a_timestamp AS DATE)

Comment: You can do it in the join

Comment: Great, that seems to work @Error_2646 - thanks so much!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a cast on the field you want as a date

```
cast(timestamp as date)
```

Answer (score 1):

If these are indeed `timestamp`, you can just use `trunc()`:

```
on trunc(t1.timestamp) = trunc(t2.timestamp)
```

If they are not timestamps or dates, you can use `to_date()` to convert them.  Or, just use the first 10 characters:

```
on left(t1.bogus_timestamp, 10) = left(t2.bogus_timestamp, 10)
```